# Repeated events on Titanium Android Calendar

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, android-calendar

can we create recurenceRule with Titanium android calendar as it is available in iOS? I want to add an event which will create repeated alerts on a particular day of week or a particular time of day. But i didn't find anyway to do that in android.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager
Keep in mind that this module will not recreate alarms after device reboot. You must do it manually.

Comment: i need to add the events in calendar , i am aware of this alarm module but i can't use it.